# Using Views to Display Taxonomy Terms Along with a single image field of the latest content type that has that taxonomy term

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

Let's say I have the following content type called Gallery that has an image field and a term reference field that can contain multiple terms from a single vocabulary.

In addition, I have several contents of these content types that share terms.

Would it be possible to create a view so that it satisfies the following conditions?

- List all terms from a certain vocabulary
- Have each term accompanied by an image (from the image field) from only the Gallery content type that uses that term
- Term and Image should be listed once. If the term is being used by more than one Gallery content, the term should appear with the image from the latest content using that specific term.

The first two conditions are very straightforward to accomplish, independently. But once I try to accomplish both at the same time, I end with a display of all images paired with a single term it's associated with.

If that image is tagged with three different terms, then that same image appears three times, each instance using each of the terms.

Further, if one term is used for x number of different content, then that term will appear x number of times.

Was just wondering if there's a way to set it up so that it's 1 term, 1 image (preferably from the latest content type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there's a module called [Views distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) that would eliminate duplicate entries due to having one field having the same values.